# Searching a table comparing values from another table (2 different columns)

Tags: sql, subquery, where-clause

I have a large table that I'm wanting to select 8 columns out of. I would be comparing it to another table with 2 columns making sure they (said columns) match exactly.

Pseudo Code:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE a AND b are matching the same rows in table 2
```

I've done this with a similar example, but only had 1 column in table 2 instead of 2 like so:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i 
FROM table t1 
WHERE a IN (SELECT * FROM table2 t2)
```

which gives me the results. But again, I now need to make sure that a AND b match the corresponding rows from table2. I've been searching but cannot find a solution. I've tried INNER JOINS, but I'm getting more results than there should be. Any help would be greatly appreciated as SQL is definitely not my wheelhouse. Also if there are any other clarifications, please let me know.

I think this is simple enough of a question, I hope. Thanks in advance!

In response to the comment:

Table 1 (has 20 million rows)

| Address | Zip | Year | Area | Name1 | Name2 | example | example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Main St | 77777 | 1999 | 2000 | John Doe | John Smith | data | data |
| 456 Main St | 88888 | 2012 | 2500 | James Doe | John Smith | data | data |
| 789 Main St | 99999 | 2018 | 2800 | Michael Doe | Michelle Doe | data | data |

Table 2 (has 7500 rows):

| Address | Zip |
| --- | --- |
| 123 Main St | 77777 |
| 321 Smith St | 66666 |
| 789 Main St | 99999 |
| 455 Highway 1 | 44444 |

Results would be expected (7500 rows)

| Address | Zip | Year | Area | Name1 | Name2 | example | example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 Main St | 77777 | 1999 | 2000 | John Doe | John Smith | data | data |
| 789 Main St | 99999 | 2018 | 2800 | Michael Doe | Michelle Doe | data | data |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text. An `INNER JOIN` is probably the way to go if you have a 1-1 cardinality between rows of both tables. But if you have 1-N or N-M, then you need to be more precise about the logic that you expe t.

Comment: @GMB sorry for the delay, but I tried regular table markup, it wouldn't work, ended up doing a screenshot instead. I hope that cleared up my question. Thanks again!

Comment: Your tables was fine, you just need to add a break (new line) before the table.

Comment: @JeromeDelaCruz: I fixed the markup in an earlier revision, let me rollback to it.

Comment: This is a bug with SO markup where it works without a linebreak in preview only. About time they fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to *filter* the content of `table1` according to the address/zip tuples that are present in `table2`.

Here is one approach using `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.address = t1.address and t2.zip = t1.zip)
```

For performance, consider an index on `table2(address, zip)`.

You can also use `in`, which sometimes brings surprising performance benefits:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (zip, address) in (select zip, address from table2)
```

Comment: I tried it with the exists, and ended up with 303,000 results vs the 7500 I was expecting...

Comment: You should look at a few of those rows and see why they were included.

Comment: @JeromeDelaCruz; it means you have multiple rows in the large table that match on a single row in the small table. So that's a 1-N relationship probably (see my comment on your question). Your sample data does not show that, and you did not tell how you want this to be adressed.

Comment: @GMB I see what you're saying, sorry for not being explicit. Table 2 is a mailing list with unique address and zip (that do not have the additional values needed). I need to get those additional values from Table 1 (which has 300+ columns as well, I just need those specific details only) I hope that makes it clearer what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It does not tell us *how* you want to handle it. When there are multiple matches in the big table, and you want to retain just one, then which one should we choose? Probably that is worth a new question @JeromeDelaCruz.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to JOIN the two tables:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b = t2.b
```

Just be aware, if Table2 can have more than one row with the same `a,b` value you can end up with duplicate results. Usually the `EXISTS()` option will perform the best, but sometimes the database can surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the insights and help with this issue of mine. I ended up with a solution that works for me. Also shoutout to Joel Coehoorn who pointed out to look at the results of my query. One thing that happened was the results gave me null values when matching on the zip code as well. Adding in a WHERE clause helped clear it up. Also turns out some of the initial data (7500 addresses and zip codes) were not formatted correctly so that was causing some issues as well.
Thanks again Stack Overflow community!

```
    SELECT PropertyAddressFull, PropertyAddressZIP, c, d, e, f FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.PropertyAddressFull=t2.address AND t1.PropertyAddressZIP=t2.propertyzip) 
  WHERE PropertyAddressFull != '' AND PropertyAddressFull IS NOT NULL AND PropertyAddressZIP != '' AND PropertyAddressZIP  IS NOT NULL
```